# Django preventing a book from being submitted twice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following a form and model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey('core.User')
```

```py
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("name", "author", "borrower")
```

```py
@login_required
def private(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            book = form.save(commit=False)
            book.save()
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render(request, 'borrow.html', {'form': form, })
```

The website allows the user to submit a new book to their own private page. The problem happens when a User tries to submit a book that has been submitted before by the same user.
Where should the verification be implemented and how?
- If I choose to verify it in the form clean method, then I have no option of getting the request to see which user it was.
- If I choose to verify it in the view, then how can I make the form invalid after it has already been validated?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you could do this, but I have listed the 2 easiest ways below:

1. Adding an error to a form field, using `form.add_error(field, error)`
2. Adding an error message using the `messages` framework

**Method 1**:

In your view, you can do the required validation, and if that validation fails, ie. the user is trying to submit the book twice, you can use (assuming your form is called `form`, as it is in your code, `title` is the field you want to add the error message to and the second parameter is the error message that you want to be displayed next to that field):

```
form.add_error('title', 'Book already taken out')
```

**Method 2**:

You can do the validation, and if that fails, you can do

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Book already taken out')
```

Then in your template, you can do

```
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Additionally, you can check if `message.tags == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR`, and then add an extra class that styles the font as red text, so that the user is more informed that it is an error.

Make sure to add

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

to your list of imports.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's almost always better to keep the view simple.

You can use the clean method in you form like:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("name", "author", "borrower")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #add the request in the ModelForm
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        #call the default super
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        #call the default clean method
        cleaned_data = super(BookForm, self).clean()
        #get the diffrents cleanned fields
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        author = cleaned_data.get('author')
        #get the user from the request
        borrower = self.request.user
        #try to get the book submited by the user from the database
        try:
            Book.objects.get(name=name, author=author, borrower=borrower)

        #if their is an error, that mean the book doesn't exist in the database at the moment
        #so we can return the cleaned data
        except Book.DoesNotExist:
            return cleaned_data

        #otherwise raise an error that could be display directly in the template in the non_field_error
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('The borrower already have this book'), code='book_already_exist')
```

> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be associated with any field in particular. They go into a special “field” (called **all**), which you can access via the non_field_errors() method if you need to. If you want to attach errors to a specific field in the form, you need to call add_error().

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because of the first bullet I've written. The user is fetched from the request and not from the data form

Comment: I just edit my code, basicaly you need to get the request from __init__ in the form, then you can use it in your clean method like self.request